Is there a way to reduce the MSE from reconstructing high dimensional vectors from 2D using uamp_model.inverse_transform?
I want to use inverse_transform to reconstruct the input value using the following code:
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import umap

data, labels = load_iris(return_X_y=True)

reducer = umap.UMAP(n_components=2, random_state=42)
embedding = reducer.fit_transform(data)

reconstructed_data = reducer.inverse_transform(embedding)

mse = mean_squared_error(data, reconstructed_data)
print(mse)

When using the iris test data set the MSE is 0.02. But when I use the intended dataset (300 dimensions) the error is between 6. and 12.. Is there a way to reduce the MSE for high dimensional data?

Reducing 300 dimensions to only 2D is extremely aggressive and will inevitably lead to significant information loss.
reducer = umap.UMAP(n_components=20, random_state=42)

Higher n_components captures more information but may lose the interpretability of low-dimensional embeddings.
